# addOnFilureListener being called when I try to upload images to firebase storage android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to firebase storage. Just so I could learn it, I am trying to upload an image from ImageView to firebase storage. My app has a button. When I click on the button, the image (from drawable) gets displayed on the imageview, along with that, the image should get uploaded to firebase storage upon clicking the button. So far, I have displayed the image upon button click, but I am unable to upload it on firebase storage.**The addOnFilureListener gets called** (I am checking which one is called by making a toast) Here is my main java file and error I am reeiving. I have also set my firebase storage to public just in case.What changes do I need to make?

```
package com.example.asad.save_photo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageMetadata;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com");

        final StorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child("images");

        Button butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back2);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back2);

                imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();

                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                        showToast("unsuccessful");
                    }
                }).addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                        //Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        showToast("success !!!!!");
                    }
                });


            }
        });

    }

    public void showToast(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}
```

And this is the error I receive

```
07-29 20:18:50.034 2888-3011/com.example.asad.save_photo E/NetworkRqFactoryProxy: NetworkRequestFactoryProxy failed with a RemoteException:
  com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsj$zza: No acceptable module found. Local version is 0 and remote version is 0.
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzsj.zza(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaml.<init>(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaml.zzi(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcyb(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzcyn(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
      at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
      at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
      at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-29 20:18:50.034 2888-3011/com.example.asad.save_photo E/UploadTask: Unable to create a network request from metadata
   android.os.RemoteException
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaml.<init>(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaml.zzi(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcyb(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzcyn(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
       at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
       at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
       at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-29 20:18:50.034 2888-3011/com.example.asad.save_photo E/StorageException: StorageException has occurred.
     An unknown error occurred, please check the HTTP result code and inner exception for server response.
      Code: -13000 HttpResult: 0
07-29 20:18:50.034 2888-3011/com.example.asad.save_photo E/StorageException: null
 android.os.RemoteException
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaml.<init>(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzaml.zzi(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference.zzcyb(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.zzcyn(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask.run(Unknown Source)
     at com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask$5.run(Unknown Source)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1113)
     at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:588)
     at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:818)
07-29 20:18:52.389 2888-2961/com.example.asad.save_photo E/Surface: getSlotFromBufferLocked: unknown buffer: 0xaa384ed0
```

Here are my firebase storage rules:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com/o {
    allow read,write;
  }
}
```

Here is my activity_main layout :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
    android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
    tools:context="com.example.asad.save_photo.MainActivity">

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_below="@+id/button"
        android:id="@+id/image" />

    <Button
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="New Button"
        android:id="@+id/button"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Is this still an unresolved problem?  Is your [new question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/38671444/4815718) an indication that you are no longer getting the exception and instead are getting a failure callback?

Comment: In both questions, failure exception is being called, but with different messages. I was getting the http result:0 but when I updated google services, it no longer gives this exception. Instead, it now gives "User does not have permission to access this object "

Answer (score 3):

Solved it. Needed to update google play services and changed my firebase storage rules to this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
        allow read, write;
      }
  }
}
```

Comment: It's helpful to know that an older version of Google Play Services was causing the initial exception.

Answer (score 0):

it worked for me.
first, you should check rules as this:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/fbstorage-fd9ef.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

second, you need check and update your Google Play services by link: (important)

```
https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.google.android.gms&hl=en
```

then rerun app. Goodluck!

Comment: read docs here @mercury0114
https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules

Answer (score 0):

For me I found that the emulator does not have play services.So i install it from sdk Manager of android studio and create a new emulator.Finally, it run on that emulator.Hope it will help out.