# User does not have permission to access this object . Firebase storage android

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-storage

I am new to firebase storage. Just so I could learn it, I made a simple app that has a button and an `ImageView`. When I click on the button, an image `(from drawable)` gets displayed on the ImageView. I have also written the code for uploading the image on Firebase, but the exception message of `onAddFailureListener` gives message **User does not have permission to access this object.** What should I do ?

```
package com.example.asad.save_photo;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageMetadata;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;

import java.io.ByteArrayOutputStream;
import java.io.File;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        FirebaseStorage storage = FirebaseStorage.getInstance();

        StorageReference storageRef = storage.getReferenceFromUrl("gs://savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com");

        final StorageReference mountainsRef = storageRef.child("asad");

        Button butt = (Button) findViewById(R.id.button);


        butt.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                ImageView imageView = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.image);
                imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back2);
                //imageView.setImageResource(R.drawable.back2);

                imageView.setDrawingCacheEnabled(true);
                imageView.buildDrawingCache();
                Bitmap bitmap = imageView.getDrawingCache();


                ByteArrayOutputStream baos = new ByteArrayOutputStream();
                bitmap.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.JPEG, 100, baos);
                final byte[] data = baos.toByteArray();

                UploadTask uploadTask = mountainsRef.putBytes(data);
                uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                    @Override
                    public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception exception) {
                        // Handle unsuccessful uploads
                        showToast(exception.getMessage());
                    }
                });
                        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                        // taskSnapshot.getMetadata() contains file metadata such as size, content-type, and download URL.
                        //Uri downloadUrl = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                        showToast("success !!!!!");
                    }
                });


            }
        });

    }

    public void showToast(String s) {
        Toast.makeText(this,s,Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
    }
}
```

Here are my firebase storage rules

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com/o {
    allow read,write;
  }
}
```

Comment: your OS version is 6.0 ? if yes then get runtime permission from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38141523/directory-creation-not-working-in-marshmallow-android/38141778#38141778

Comment: Nope. My OS version is 4.2

Comment: Have you add permissions in manifest file?

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />

This is the only one I have added. I am really new to it so please feel free to point out mistakes

Comment: <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />

This one too.

Comment: You need to change your security rules in firebase storage rules

Answer (score 129, accepted):

Update your security rules with `match /{allPaths=**}` to indicate that public read and write access is allowed on all paths:

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Various default rules are provides in the tabs of the [Sample Rules](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/security/start#sample-rules) section of the documentation.

Comment: where do you add this?

Comment: @rosualin: At the [Firebase Console](https://console.firebase.google.com/) for your project

Answer (score 37):

Change your storage rules in Firebase console

[image]

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I have that exact setup and am still receiving that error.

Comment: Worked for me after removing : if request.auth != null

Answer (score 30):

Follow these steps

1. Go to "Storage"
2. Select "Rules" tab and edit rules as per below:

##### if your application have authentication feature(login) then use this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

##### if your application does not have login feature(directly any user can access storage) then use this:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 13):

Go to storage -> Rules tab

add this

```
// Anyone can read or write to the bucket, even non-users of your app.
// Because it is shared with Google App Engine, this will also make
// files uploaded via GAE public.
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 11):

Just go to Storage - Rules. Enter the rule as following, replacing the bucket name with your own bucket name. You can find the bucket name by going to Storage - Files.

It should look something like this:
myapplication-xxxx.appspot.com

That's all you need. You don't need to enable authentication, if you are doing it for testing purposes only. If you need authentication, you can add it later.

[image]

Comment: You literally helped me, my problem was that i copy this match from somewhere else and it didn't match my application name at all. After a while i have found your explanation and that's it, I own you a drink :) .

Answer (score 4):

please go to your storage/rules folder in firebase and paste this following code.

```
 rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The issue is with your firebase storage rules. Change it to

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Make sure the `if request.auth != null`

Answer (score 1):

Allow write by only authenticated user, but read by all:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read;
      allow write: if request.auth != null;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

These soloutions really did not solve my problem.

what have solved my problem are those lines:

in app module

```
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-database:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-storage:15.0.0'
implementation 'com.google.firebase:firebase-auth:15.0.0'
```

and this code for uploading and getting a download link

```
private void uploadImageToFirebase(Bitmap bmp) {

    try {
        String file_path = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory().getAbsolutePath() +
                "/news";
        File dir = new File(file_path);
        if (!dir.exists())
            dir.mkdirs();
        File file = new File(dir, "sketchpad" + "_" + ".png");
        FileOutputStream fOut = new FileOutputStream(file);
        bmp.compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.PNG, 100, fOut);
        fOut.flush();
        fOut.close();
        Log.i("SECONDACTIVITY", "ADDED SUCCESSFULLY");

        Uri file2 = Uri.fromFile(file);


        //Now Upload
        final StorageReference storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference();
        StorageReference riversRef = storageRef.child(file.getName());
        UploadTask uploadTask;
        uploadTask = riversRef.putFile(file2);
        progressDialog.show();
        progressDialog.setCancelable(false);


        uploadTask.addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred()) / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount();
                progressDialog.incrementProgressBy((int) progress);
            }
        });
        uploadTask.addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
                Uri DownloadLink = taskSnapshot.getDownloadUrl();
                String imgUrl = DownloadLink.toString();
                FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference().child("image_link").setValue(imgUrl);
            }
        });
        uploadTask.addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                progressDialog.dismiss();
            }
        });


    } catch (IOException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/fir-upload-a2fa6.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Please, can you extend your answer with more detailed explanation? This will be very useful for understanding. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

**Firebase Storage Error (solved)**
**1.** Go to firebase console under the project you are working on
**2.** Under storage on the firebase console and under rules edit  the service firebase.storage to.

```
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am adding this answer hoping it will help someone, in Firebase:

1. go to "Storage"
2. Select "Rules" tab and edit rules as per below:

   ```
   service firebase.storage {
      match /b/{bucket}/o {
        match /{allPaths=**} {
          // Allow access by all users
          allow read, write: if request.auth != null;
        }
      }
    }
   ```

Note: make sure you have it exactly as above, do not replace {bucket} for your project name.

Answer (score 0):

Firebase Storage Error (solved) 1. Go to firebase console under the project you are working on 2. Under storage on the firebase console and under rules edit the service firebase.storage to.

```
service firebase.storage {
 match /b/{bucket}/o {
  match /{allPaths=**} {
  allow read, write;
  }
 }
}
```

Note: If have't solve this problem then check your firebase plan expires.

Answer (score 0):

I have just changed the date like before it was `timestamp.date(2023, 3, 27)` to `timestamp.date(2023, 6, 27)`;

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write: if
          request.time < timestamp.date(2023, 6, 27);
    }
  }
}
```