# Object does not exist at location. Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404

Tags: java, android, firebase

When I am trying to upload an image to firebase I get a failed message then I get the error message in my LogCat that says "StorageException has occurred    Object does not exist at location.     Code: -13010 HttpResult: 404" then it says "The server has terminated the upload session". This is the only code file that deals with uploading images.

````
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.ContentResolver;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;

import android.view.View;
import android.webkit.MimeTypeMap;
import android.widget.EditText;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.appcompat.app.AppCompatActivity;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Continuation;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.database.DatabaseReference;
import com.google.firebase.database.FirebaseDatabase;
import com.google.firebase.storage.FirebaseStorage;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageReference;
import com.google.firebase.storage.StorageTask;
import com.google.firebase.storage.UploadTask;
import com.theartofdev.edmodo.cropper.CropImage;

import java.util.HashMap;

public class PostActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private Uri mImageUri;
    String miUrlOk = "";
    private StorageTask uploadTask;
    StorageReference storageRef;

    ImageView close, image_added;
    TextView post;
    EditText description;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_post);

        close = findViewById(R.id.close);
        image_added = findViewById(R.id.image_added);
        post = findViewById(R.id.post);
        description = findViewById(R.id.description);

        storageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("posts");

        close.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                finish();
            }
        });

        post.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                uploadImage_10();
            }
        });


        CropImage.activity()
                .setAspectRatio(1,1)
                .start(PostActivity.this);
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri){
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadImage_10(){
        final ProgressDialog pd = new ProgressDialog(this);
        pd.setMessage("Posting");
        pd.show();
        if (mImageUri != null){
            final StorageReference fileReference = storageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            uploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri);
            uploadTask.continueWithTask(new Continuation<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot, Task<Uri>>() {
                @Override
                public Task<Uri> then(@NonNull Task<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot> task) throws Exception {
                    if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                        throw task.getException();
                    }
                    return fileReference.getDownloadUrl();
                }
            }).addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<Uri>() {
                @Override
                public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<Uri> task) {
                    if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                        Uri downloadUri = task.getResult();
                        miUrlOk = downloadUri.toString();

                        DatabaseReference reference = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("Posts");

                        String postid = reference.push().getKey();

                        HashMap<String, Object> hashMap = new HashMap<>();
                        hashMap.put("postid", postid);
                        hashMap.put("postimage", miUrlOk);
                        hashMap.put("description", description.getText().toString());
                        hashMap.put("publisher", FirebaseAuth.getInstance().getCurrentUser().getUid());

                        reference.child(postid).setValue(hashMap);

                        pd.dismiss();

                        startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
                        finish();

                    } else {
                        Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "Failed", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                    }
                }
            }).addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                @Override
                public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                    Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            });

        } else {
            Toast.makeText(PostActivity.this, "No image selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == CropImage.CROP_IMAGE_ACTIVITY_REQUEST_CODE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {

            CropImage.ActivityResult result = CropImage.getActivityResult(data);
            mImageUri = result.getUri();

            image_added.setImageURI(mImageUri);
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "Something gone wrong!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            startActivity(new Intent(PostActivity.this, MainActivity.class));
            finish();
        }
    }
}```
````

Answer (score 1):

Have you already initiated your Firestorage? I got the same code and HTTP result, once I triggered it from web the error code changed from 404 to 403.
if you have the same problem, try this link
[User does not have permission to access this object . Firebase storage android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671444/user-does-not-have-permission-to-access-this-object-firebase-storage-android)