# Firebase storage,relatime database android :User does not have permission to access this object

Tags: java, android, firebase, firebase-storage, firebase-security

I made a simple app that has a button and an ImageView. When I click on the button, an image (from drawable) gets displayed on the ImageView. I have also written the code for uploading the image on Firebase, but the exception message of onAddFailureListener gives the message User does not have permission to access this object. What should I do?
This answer does not help me.

- [User does not have permission to access this object . Firebase storage android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38671444/user-does-not-have-permission-to-access-this-object-firebase-storage-android)

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static final int PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST = 1;

    private Button mButtonChooseImage;
    private Button mButtonUpload;
    private TextView mTextViewShowUploads;
    private EditText mEditTextFileName;
    private ImageView mImageView;
    private ProgressBar mProgressBar;

    private Uri mImageUri;

    private StorageReference mStorageRef;
    private DatabaseReference mDatabaseRef;

    private StorageTask mUploadTask;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        mButtonChooseImage = findViewById(R.id.button_choose_image);
        mButtonUpload = findViewById(R.id.button_upload);
        mTextViewShowUploads = findViewById(R.id.text_view_show_uploads);
        mEditTextFileName = findViewById(R.id.edit_text_file_name);
        mImageView = findViewById(R.id.image_view);
        mProgressBar = findViewById(R.id.progress_bar);

        mStorageRef = FirebaseStorage.getInstance().getReference("uploads");
        mDatabaseRef = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference("uploads");

        mButtonChooseImage.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openFileChooser();
            }
        });

        mButtonUpload.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if (mUploadTask != null && mUploadTask.isInProgress()) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload in progress", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                } else {
                    uploadFile();
                }
            }
        });

        mTextViewShowUploads.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                openImagesActivity();
            }
        });
    }

    private void openFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(intent, PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }

    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

        if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK
                && data != null && data.getData() != null) {
            mImageUri = data.getData();

            Picasso.get().load(mImageUri).into(mImageView);
        }
    }

    private String getFileExtension(Uri uri) {
        ContentResolver cR = getContentResolver();
        MimeTypeMap mime = MimeTypeMap.getSingleton();
        return mime.getExtensionFromMimeType(cR.getType(uri));
    }

    private void uploadFile() {

        if (mImageUri != null) {
            StorageReference fileReference = mStorageRef.child(System.currentTimeMillis()
                    + "." + getFileExtension(mImageUri));

            mUploadTask = fileReference.putFile(mImageUri)
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            Handler handler = new Handler();
                            handler.postDelayed(new Runnable() {
                                @Override
                                public void run() {
                                    mProgressBar.setProgress(0);
                                }
                            }, 500);

                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Upload successful", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                            Upload upload = new Upload(mEditTextFileName.getText().toString().trim(),
               /*
                                    taskSnapshot.getMetadata().getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);

                */
                                    Objects.requireNonNull(taskSnapshot.getMetadata()).getReference().getDownloadUrl().toString());
                            String uploadId = mDatabaseRef.push().getKey();
                            assert uploadId != null;
                            mDatabaseRef.child(uploadId).setValue(upload);
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnProgressListener(new OnProgressListener<UploadTask.TaskSnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onProgress(UploadTask.TaskSnapshot taskSnapshot) {
                            double progress = (100.0 * taskSnapshot.getBytesTransferred() / taskSnapshot.getTotalByteCount());
                            mProgressBar.setProgress((int) progress);
                        }
                    });
        } else {
            Toast.makeText(this, "No file selected", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }

    private void openImagesActivity() {
        Intent intent = new Intent(this, ImagesActivity.class);
        startActivity(intent);
    }
}
```

```
Realtime Database
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": true,
    ".write": true
  }
}

Storage
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/savephoto-a1cc3.appspot.com/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      // Allow access by all users
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I have seen a comment in your code that sounds like this "Allow access by all users", then I recommend you use the following rules:

```
rules_version = '2';
service firebase.storage {
  match /b/{bucket}/o {
    match /{allPaths=**} {
      allow read, write;
    }
  }
}
```

For testing purposes, it will work but I encourage you to change them when you'll launch the application.